# Qiskit: unexpected get_statevector output in Jupyter

Tags: qiskit

I executed the following code in a Jupyter notebook:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, transpile

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0,1)

backend = Aer.get_backend("aer_simulator")
qc.save_statevector()

tqc = transpile(qc, backend)
job = backend.run(tqc)
result = job.result()
statevector = result.get_statevector(tqc, 4)
print(statevector)
```

and receive the output:

```
Statevector([0.7071+0.j, 0.    +0.j, 0.    +0.j, 0.7071+0.j],
            dims=(2, 2))
```

But, according to the `get_statevector()` [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.get_statevector.html#qiskit.result.Result.get_statevector), the `get_statevector()` method returns list of complex amplitudes. So, I would expect only a list of complex numbers in the output. What is the `dims=(2,2)` part of the output? Why is it appearing in the output and how can I get the output to reflect the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in the documentation, introduced here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/7277

You can get the list of complex with `statevector.data`.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, the documentation you linked to is incorrect. The `get_statevector()` method actually returns a `qiskit.quantum_info.states.statevector.Statevector` object (you can confirm this by changing your last line of code to `print(type(statevector))`) the documentation for which is found [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.html).

As for the printed output you asked about, it is the result of calling a `print()` statement on an object, which can have a variety of results. In this case, calling `print()` on a `Statevector` object calls that object's built in function `__repr__`. Looking at the [source code](https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/quantum_info/states/statevector.html#Statevector) for the `Statevector` object we can see that `dims=(2,2)` appears because `__repr__` is printing the dimensions of the `_op_shape` attribute.

Rather than worrying too much about that attribute of the code, however, we can see what the `dims=(2,2)` printout is telling us just by changing your line of code `qc = QuantumCircuit(2)` to `qc = QuantumCircuit(n)` for $n=3, 4$, etc, because when $n=3$, `dims=(2,2,2)`, while when $n=4$, `dims=(2,2,2,2)`, etc. Since $n$ gives the number of qubits in the system, and since qubits are two-level systems (i.e. they live in a two-dimensional vector space), we see that `dims` just tells us the overall dimensionality of the system, with each additional qubit increasing that dimensionality by a factor of two.

Finally, if you change your code from `statevector = result.get_statevector(tqc, 4)` to `statevector = result.get_statevector(tqc, 4).data` then your `statevector` variable will just be a list of complex numbers like you want.